# CentOS 8 on Hyper-v - cannot establish internet connection

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ethernet, hyper-v

I am having problems with configuring internet connection for CentOS VM hosted on Hyper-V

Initially I installed OS with 1 internal network card. Configured it and now I am able to communicate between VMs hosted on mu computer - that's eth0.

Next I added external network card and rebooted VMs. Can't make it work from here..
Any ideas what might be wrong here?

I use same external switch for Windows server and it works fine.

At first device was disconnected

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
eth0    ethernet  connected     eth0
eth1    ethernet  disconnected  --
lo      loopback  unmanaged     --
```

nmcli con add type ethernet con-name zew ifname eth1

Now device is connected

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
eth0    ethernet  connected  eth0
eth1    ethernet  connected  zew
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Here's results of cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-zew

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=zew
UUID=ed19cc64-5446-4d96-9564-76dcc840645b
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
```

nmcli connection show is all green

```
NAME  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
eth0  86933dbd-7c39-45b9-b9cf-0f2a16cb7d34  ethernet  eth0
zew   ed19cc64-5446-4d96-9564-76dcc840645b  ethernet  eth1
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search home thebest.local
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

results of ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:19:10:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.35/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7259:9d8a:acc7:52e0/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:19:10:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.38/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft 86126sec preferred_lft 86126sec
    inet6 fe80::3af6:a29a:6111:1d34/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

when I try to ping google

```
[root@ora-linux network-scripts]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.35 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: Seems like there is a strange value in resolve.conf. I was playing with adding hostname to reflect windows domain, but I’ve since removed it from /etc/hostname. Not sure where it’s coming from now

Comment: Check whether you have two `default` routes with the same / no metric in `ip r`. If `eth0` is not used for Internet connection, you should avoid having a default route that makes use of it added. (If it's from the DHCP server, it could be misconfiguration on the host side. Either way, you can tell your network manager to ignore it.)